# i don't know how to run my simulation in castalia?

Tags: simulation, omnet++

i installed **castalia** but i don't know how to run **my simulation** in castalia?
What files are required to run simulation or Create output files??

I get this error in my simulation:

> Program "g++" not found in PATH

Comment: Hi Marjan, could you please share your codes, the simulation setting and what you have done so far?

Comment: Could you provide more information: version of Castalia, version of OMNeT++, OS?

Comment: omnetpp-4.2 and castalia-3.2

Comment: How do you try to run Castalia? Have you read [Castalia - User Manual.docx](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/master/Castalia%20-%20User%20Manual.docx)?

Comment: yes, but I do not have a complete example of how to write and run the program in Castalia

Comment: It seems you have not installed Castalia. Have you followed all steps in the Installation Guide successfully?

Comment: yes i have followed all steps in the Installation Guide successfully

Comment: I installed the castalia on Windows